# nautilus - disable drag and drop

Tags: nautilus

I'm working on a sensible system. I do files stuff with default nautilus in Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04.

If I do a wrong click+movement, some folder is moved somewhere else. I know no ways undo this operation and I no no ways to see a logfile of whats happend.

I want to disable the drag and drop move/copy function in nautilus.

Comment: or is there a file-browser which has the ability to disable drag&drop?